# RegCreateKeyEX returns ERROR_INVALID_FUNCTION

Tags: c++, windows, error-handling, registry

I am writing a program that needs to create/delete a registry key. I am having a problem that the code to create the key returns `ERROR_INVALID_FUNCTION`.

If you look in the registry the key has been created so I'm not sure what the impact of this error is.

```
The value of key is "SOFTWARE\\Wow6432Node\\COMPANY\\APPLICATION"
```

The code is:

```
int RegistryViewer::CreateRegistryLocation(const char* key)
{
    HKEY hkey = 0;
    int retVal = RegistryViewer::OpenRegistryLocation(key);
    if(retVal != ERROR_SUCCESS)
    {
        retVal = RegCreateKeyEx(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, CString(key), 0, NULL,REG_OPTION_NON_VOLATILE, KEY_WOW64_32KEY | KEY_WRITE, NULL, &hkey, NULL);
RegCloseKey(hkey);  
}

    return retVal;
}
```

Is the problem that although the key is created, it's unable to set the permissions correctly?

Thanks.

Comment: I don't know why it fails with that particular error, but I doubt it would do what you want anyway. When you specify `KEY_WOW64_32KEY`, don't explicitly reference "Wow6432Node". The redirection is automatic. Just use `"SOFTWARE\\COMPANY\\APPLICATION"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Going to answer my own question in case it's helpful to others in future. I think I had two problems that were limiting access to the registry key, firstly I was opening it twice (once to see it existed and then when it was created), secondly I was assigning it `KEY_WRITE` permissions. Since `RegCreateKeyEx` opens a key if it already exists the first check was pointless and may have been holding the resource. I'm not sure the second thing was a problem but since it's changed in the code I thought I'd mention it.

Working code looks like this:

```
//Create a registry location
int RegistryViewer::CreateRegistryLocation(const char* key)
{
    HKEY hkey = 0;
    int retVal = RegCreateKeyEx(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, CString(key), 0, NULL, REG_OPTION_NON_VOLATILE, KEY_WOW64_32KEY | KEY_ALL_ACCESS, NULL, &hkey, NULL);

    if(retVal == ERROR_SUCCESS)
        RegCloseKey(hkey);

    return retVal;
}
```

The comment by eryksun was useful for another issue though as I was manually checking which part of the registry to use and he enabled me to remove that check.